ArcPy automated compression 'A check constraint violation has occurred. [sde.DEFAULT]'
We have an automatic Python script for ArcMap 10.8.1 which compresses our database nightly after employees have finished their work.
We're getting this error preventing the automatic script to run, we can still run the compression manually through ArcCatalog
A check constraint violation has occurred. [sde.DEFAULT][STATE_ID = 683660]
A check constraint violation has occurred. [sde.DEFAULT]

Does anyone have any insight to what this means, or how we can start to debug the situation deeper?

Can you post the script (edit your question and add the code)?  Preferably, post the most cut-down minimal version of the script which still produces the error.  This may require some trial and error, to get the the minimal error-prone version of the script, but this trial and error process may also isolate which part of the script is causing the error.

Try the Diagnose Version Tables tool and let us know the results (add any relevant information to your original question post).  See:  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/diagnose-version-tables.htm
